# Use one Laravel migrations table per database

Tags: php, laravel-4, database-migration

I work in a project that uses multiple databases. It seems like Laravel only uses the migrations-table in the database that is set as default. I would like one migrations table per database that logs the migrations that have been done to that specific database. Is this possible?

I have defined the databases in the config like this:

```
'connections' => [
    'db1' => array(
        'driver'    => 'mysql',
        'host'      => 'db1.host',
        'database'  => 'db1',
        'username'  => 'username',
        'password'  => 'password',
    ),
    'db2' => [
        'driver'    => 'mysql',
        'host'      => 'db2.host',
        'database'  => 'db2',
        'username'  => 'username',
        'password'  => 'password',
    ]
],
```

I also made the first database (db1) the default one

```
'default' => 'db1'
```

I install the migrations table on both databases

```
artisan migrate:install --database=db1
artisan migrate:install --database=db2
```

After that i proceed to create a couple of database specifc migrations

Create table test1 in db1 database:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateTest1Table extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::connection('db1')->create('test1', function(Blueprint $table)
        {
            $table->increments('id')->unsigned();
        });
    }

    public function down()
    {
        Schema::connection('db1')->drop('test1');
    }
}
```

Create table test2 in db2 database:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateTest2Table extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::connection('db2')->create('test2', function(Blueprint $table)
        {
            $table->increments('id')->unsigned();
        });
    }

    public function down()
    {
        Schema::connection('db2')->drop('test2');
    }
}
```

I now run the migrations

```
artisan migrate
```

### Expected outcome

#### db1.migrations

```
+-----------------------------+-------+
| migration                   | batch |
+-----------------------------+-------+
| create_test1_table_in_db1   |     1 |
+-----------------------------+-------+
```

#### db2.migrations

```
+-----------------------------+-------+
| migration                   | batch |
+-----------------------------+-------+
| create_test2_table_in_db2   |     1 |
+-----------------------------+-------+
```

### Actual outcome

#### db1.migrations

```
+-----------------------------+-------+
| migration                   | batch |
+-----------------------------+-------+
| create_test1_table_in_db1   |     1 |
| create_test2_table_in_db2   |     1 |
+-----------------------------+-------+
```

#### db2.migrations

```
+-----------------------------+-------+
| migration                   | batch |
+-----------------------------+-------+
Empty set
```

Comment: Just realized that it might be a bad idea to have a migrations-table for each database in regards to rollbacks. Lets say you have three databases and the latest migration caused changes to two of them. When you want to rollback you no longer know what databases you need to rollback on since there's no longer a global batch number. Thoughts?

Comment: It mostly depends on your needs. If you have your a single application with the data storage structure distributed between multiple servers (for performance or whatever other reasons you may have), then one common migration file is all you need. If however you have smaller applications/modules that might only use databases on one server and you want to update them independently, then having separate migration tables would be beneficial (keep in mind that `migrate:rollback` also has the `--database` parameter).

Answer (score 50, accepted):

> Article on usage of multiple database usage in Laravel -
> https://stackcoder.in/posts/laravel-7x-multiple-database-connections-migrations-relationships-querying

Use the `--database` parameter with the `migrate` command and store the migrations for each database in separate directories.

You could have separate directories in `app/database/migrations` for each of your database (in your case `db1` and `db2`) and store the appropriate migrations in each directory. Then you could run the migrations like this:

```
artisan migrate --database="db1" --path="app/database/migrations/db1"
artisan migrate --database="db2" --path="app/database/migrations/db2"
```

This way your `migrations` table will be independent for each database.

If you want to go the extra mile and automate the process you could create your custom command that will run all the migrations at once. You can create the command like this (use `make:console` for Laravel 5.0 up to 5.2 or `make:command` for Laravel 5.2+):

```
artisan command:make MigrateAllCommand --command=migrate:all
```

This will create a new file `app/commands/MigrateAllCommand.php`. Your command's `fire` method would look something like this:

```
public function fire()
{
    foreach (Config::get('database.connections') as $name => $details)
    {
        $this->info('Running migration for "' . $name . '"');
        $this->call('migrate', array('--database' => $name, '--path' => 'app/database/migrations/' . $name));
    }
}
```

This will work provided the name of the database configuration key is the same as the migration directory name. You can then just call it like this:

```
artisan migrate:all
```

You can check the [Laravel Command Docs](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/commands) for more info.

Comment: Since Laravel 5, it should be `handle()` method be used, instead of `fire()`. + Path should be without `app/` prefix, just `'database/migrations/' . $name`

Comment: I have written a complete article for the sam you can check it at <a href="https://stackcoder.in/posts/laravel-7x-multiple-database-connections-migrations-relationships-querying?referer=stackoverflow.com">Laravel 7.x Multiple Database Connections, Migrations, Relationships & Querying</a>

Comment: @ChannaveerHakari you have missed the seeds part!

Comment: @francisco Okay I will cover that part at the earliest.