# How to save Laravel migration information in corresponding database when have multiple Databases?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, migration

I have two databases (db1 and db2). 
When I create migrations, I can choose a connection with ::connection() method.

When I run the migrations command

```
php artisan migrate
```

, the tables are created and saved correctly in corresponding database, but all the migration info is saved to 'migrations' table in the first database.

What I would like to do is to save the migrations data in the corresponding database.

Comment: I think this is answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26654846/use-one-laravel-migrations-table-per-database