# laravel multiple databases with multiple migration tables

Tags: database, laravel, migration, multiple-databases

I am trying to set up a multiple database application in laravel 5. I have a database A and a second database B. In database A there are my main models. Now I tried to write a migration file that creates a new table in database B. This works, because I can set the connection to database B in the schema builder like this:

```
Schema::connection('foo')->create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id'); 
});
```

But the problem here is, that the migrations table is still in database A. I want to have a migrations table in database A for all of the tables which are in database A and another migrations table in database B for all of the tables which are in database B.

I am searching for something like this:

```
Schema::connection('foo')->migrations_table_connection('foo')->create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id'); 
});
```

Is there any way to do that?
THX

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I found it out with the help of this [Use one Laravel migrations table per database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26654846/use-one-laravel-migrations-table-per-database) and post the answer here for others.

In order to separate the migrations you need to run the migrate command with the database option like this:

```
php artisan migrate --database="nameOfConnection"
```

Comment: what if you have several databases as secondary, for e.g. a situation where you have one main database with a table of fiscal-years and for each fiscal-year record you have a separate database... in that case, how would you go around running migrations in all the fiscal-year tables?