# Laravel 5.7 problems migrating split read-write database

Tags: mysql, database, migration, laravel-5.7, read-write

I am experiencing the following scenario:

I want to split my database into separate read and write databases. For that reason i've setup the config/database.php

```
    'mysql' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'write' => ['host' => env('DB_HOST_WRITE', 'localhost'),],
        'read'  => ['host' => env('DB_HOST_READ', 'localhost'),],
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
        'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
        'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
        'prefix' => '',
        'strict' => true,
        'engine' => null,
    ],
```

For `DB_HOST_WRITE` and `DB_HOST_READ` I've set the IP addresses for the servers where the databases are running on.

For `DB_DATABASE`, `DB_USERNAME`, `DB_PASSWORD` I've setup the database name and the login credentials.

Both servers are reachable, when I try to access them using mysql console commands like this: `mysql -u USERNAME -h IPADDRESS -p`

Here is the problem: When I attempt to run my migrations from a third server like this

```
php artisan migrate
```

But only the write database gets set up.

Is this the expected behaviour?

Do I have to migrate each database manually?

Is there a flag for the migration command, that allows me to specify the connection i want to migrate on?

I cant find anything about read write database migrations when I google for it.

There was no further database setup done. My information source is the following guide: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/database#read-and-write-connections

Links to useful guides or solution suggestions are very welcome.

Thanks for your attention.

Comment: How is your database replication configured between your databases?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26654846/use-one-laravel-migrations-table-per-database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to @Travis Britz: Thanks for the hint. I was missing the term "MySQL Replication", what is not commented in the laravel documentations. I was mistakenly thinking laravel algorithms are handling the synchronisation on their own, what is in fact not happening.

Synchronization between databaseservers is handled by MySQL internal mechanisms

[image]

With these MySQL algorithms I was able to achieve a communication structure like that, what might be a common task in the deployment step of web applications:

[image]

I followed this guide by digital ocean to setup a mysql replication manually: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-master-slave-replication-in-mysql

Digital Ocean is the server provider i'm hosting my applications at.

Images are taken from:
https://www.toptal.com/mysql/mysql-master-slave-replication-tutorial

Best regards.