# Use a specific database connection when I run database migration

Tags: php, laravel-5, database-migration

I have the following database migration that I use it for testing:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Support\Facade\App;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class TestWebsitedbMigration extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        if(App::environment() == "testing")
        {
            ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');
            DB::unprepared( file_get_contents( "resources/database_dumps/my_website.sql" ) );
        }
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        if(App::environment() == "testing")
        {
            // Burn it down!!!!
            // But needs some im plementation first
        }
    }
}
```

The whole idea is to use the migrations in order to create and nuking databases when I run `phpunit` integration tests. Because of no prior migration script existance I created a schema-only database dump in `resources/database_dumps/my_website.sql`.

And I use that dump in order to load the schema into my database. BUT my application has 2 database connections:

```
return [

    'default'     => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'brock_lesnar'),
    'connections' => [
        'seth_rollins' => [
            'driver'   => 'pgsql',
            'host'     => env('DB_API_HOST', '192.168.10.70'),
            'port'     => env('DB_API_PORT', '5432'),
            'database' => env('DB_API_DATABASE', 'etable_api'),
            'username' => env('DB_API_USERNAME', ''),
            'password' => env('DB_API_PASSWORD', ''),
            'charset'  => 'utf8',
            'prefix'   => '',
            'schema'   => 'public',
            'sslmode'  => 'prefer',
        ],

        'brock_lesnar' => [
            'driver'   => 'pgsql',
            'host' => env('BROCK_DB_HOST', '192.168.10.70'),
            'port'     => env('BROCK_DB_PORT', '5432'),
            'database' => env('BROCK_DB_DATABASE', 'etable'),
            'username' => env('BROCK_DB_USERNAME', ''),
            'password' => env('BROCK_DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'charset'  => 'utf8',
            'prefix'   => '',
            'schema'   => 'public',
            'sslmode'  => 'prefer',
        ],
    ],

    'migrations' => 'migrations',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Redis Databases
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Redis is an open source, fast, and advanced key-value store that also
    | provides a richer set of commands than a typical key-value systems
    | such as APC or Memcached. Laravel makes it easy to dig right in.
    |
     */

    'redis' => [
        'client'  => 'predis',
        'default' => [
            'host'     => env('REDIS_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', NULL),
            'port'     => env('REDIS_PORT', 6379),
            'database' => 0,
        ],
    ],
];
```

And I want to run this migration into the `seth_rollins` database connection. Do you have any idea how to do that? As you can see my default database is the `brock_lestnar` one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have this toy Migration:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class MakeDummyTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    { 
        $schema=Schema::connection('seth_rollins');
        $schema->create('dummy_table', function (Blueprint $table) {
                $table->increments('id');
                $table->string('lover')->nullable()->default('Becky Lynch')
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {     
       // Destroy it here
    }
}
```

You can specify via the `Schema::connection('seth_rollins');` your connection you want to run your migration. Also you can specify a folder as well on where the tests will run as well. Assuming you made the folder then run:

```
  php artisan make:migration --path './database/migrations/seth_rollins' ^migration_name^ --table=^table_name^
```

And you can run migrations as seen in this [asnwer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26657029/4706711).